# Possible to get a British passport?

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship, job-hunting, foreign-employment

Two questions:

1: I want to ask if it is possible for my sister to get a British passport? She was born in England but we moved before she was one year old. Our parents are not British so is it possible for her to get one??

2: I would also like to ask if it is possible to apply for a job in England if you live outside the country ??

Comment: When was your born? Were either of your parents permanent residents of the UK or citizens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [eligibility requirements for a British passport](https://www.gov.uk/british-passport-eligibility) require you to be a British National. The most common type of British National is a British citizen. The online [British citizen check](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen) will tell you if your sister is a citizen or not. If she is not a citizen, there are two main routes to [become a British citizen](https://www.gov.uk/becoming-a-british-citizen). The first is by naturalization and takes over 5 years. The second is to "simply" [register as a British citizen](https://www.gov.uk/register-british-citizen). Again based on the information provided, assuming your sister was [born after 1983](https://www.gov.uk/register-british-citizen/born-in-uk-after-1983) she would have had to live in the UK until she was 10 years old.

Comment: "From the information you have provided, the British citizen check says your sister is not a citizen." From the information that's provided, it's impossible to tell, because if either of her parents were settled in the UK when she was born, then she is automatically a British citizen by birth, and whether her parents were settled was not provided.

Comment: @user102008 fair enough. I edited my answer to remove the claim about status and left it more general.

Comment: I don't believe there is a requirement for someone to live in the UK until ten if one of her parents was settled in Britain

Answer (score 4):

There is a useful online service titled [Check if you're a British citizen](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen) which you can use to determine your sister's eligibility. It asks a few simple questions and gives you an answer. The answer will depend on factors such as:

- what date she was born
- whether your parents were "legally settled" in the UK at the time

Comment: While you need to be a British citizen to get a passport, there are a few loopholes where you might not be a citizen automatically, but might be eligible to become one. For example [if you are born and lived in the UK until 10 years old](https://www.gov.uk/register-british-citizen/overview) you can register to become a citizen.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm unfamiliar with all the possible avenues to obtain British citizenship, and it sounds like there are quite a few.

Comment: You do not even have to be a British citizen to get a British passport (although that is the most common way).